# PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while executing C:\Users\ipeki\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis\..\solverdir\cbc\win\64\cbc.exe

Tags: python, pulp

I am using anaconda spyder for coding. Working on my thesis' mathematical model, i used pulp library to solve it.

Everytime i run my code this error occurs:

```
PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while executing C:\Users\ipeki\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis\..\solverdir\cbc\win\64\cbc.exe
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
import pulp as plp
model = plp.LpProblem("Ornek", plp.LpMinimize)
#sets
set_E=range(0,20) #affected area
set_S=range(0,9) #shelters
set_V=range(0,40) #available veicle
set_D=range(1,10) #set of vehicle depots
set_N=range(0,60) #set of all nodes in people evacuation operations
#parameters
tr={(i,j):random.randint(1,30) for i in set_N for j in set_N} #transportation time from node i to node j
d={(i):random.randint(10,200) for i in set_N} #demand of affected area 
c={(i):random.randint(10,160) for i in set_S} #capacity of shelters
cap=int(45) #capacity of vehicle
t={(i):random.randint(1,40) for i in set_E} #service time at node i
Mbig=int(100)
#decision variables
x_vars = [[[plp.LpVariable("x%d%d%d" % (v,i,j), cat='Binary') 
        for v in set_V] 
        for i in set_N]
        for j in set_N]
y_vars = [[plp.LpVariable("y%d%d" % (v,i), cat='Binary') 
        for v in set_V] 
        for i in set_N] 
z_vars = [plp.LpVariable("z%d" % (v), cat='Binary') 
        for v in set_V] 
q_vars = [[plp.LpVariable("q%d%d" % (v,i), lowBound=0, upBound=45, cat='Integer') 
        for v in set_V] 
        for i in set_N]
T_vars = [[plp.LpVariable("T%d%d" % (v,i), lowBound=random.randint(0,10), upBound=random.randint(11,30), cat='Integer') 
        for v in set_V] 
        for i in set_N]
#objective function
for v in set_V:
    for i in (set_E and set_S):
        objective=plp.lpSum(T_vars[v][i])
        
#C1
for j in set_E:
    for i in set_D:
            model += plp.lpSum([x_vars[v][i][j] for v in set_V]) == ([z_vars[v] for v in set_V])

#C2
for i in (set_D and set_E and set_S):
    if i != j:
        model+=plp.lpSum([x_vars[v][i][j] for i in (set_D and set_E) for v in set_V for j in set_E])==plp.lpSum([x_vars[v][i][j] for i in (set_E and set_S) for v in set_V for j in set_E])

#C3
for v in set_V:
    model += plp.lpSum([q_vars[v][i] for i in set_E]) == ([d[i] for i in set_E])
#C4
for v in set_V:
        model+= ([cap*y_vars[v][i] for i in (set_E and set_S)])>=([q_vars[v][i] for i in (set_E and set_S)])

#C5
for j in (set_E and set_D):
    if i != j:
        model += plp.lpSum([x_vars[v][j][i] for i in set_E for v in set_V]) == ([y_vars[v][i] for i in set_E for v in set_V])
#C6
for j in (set_E and set_S):
    if i != j:
        model += plp.lpSum([x_vars[v][j][i] for i in set_S for v in set_V]) == ([y_vars[v][i] for i in set_S for v in set_V])
#C7
for i in (set_S and set_E):
    model+=plp.lpSum([q_vars[v][i] for i in set_S for v in set_V])==plp.lpSum([q_vars[v][i] for i in set_E for v in set_V]) 
#C8
for i in set_E:
    model += plp.lpSum([q_vars[v][i] for v in set_V]) <= ([cap*z_vars[v] for v in set_V])
    
#C9
for v in set_V:
    model += plp.lpSum([q_vars[v][i] for i in set_S]) <= ([c[i] for i in set_S])

#C10
for v in set_V:
    model += plp.lpSum([z_vars[v]]) <= set_V

#C11
model+= ([T_vars[v][i] for i in set_D for v in set_V])==0

model.setObjective(objective)
model.solve()
print("Status:", model.status)
```

Comment: Is there more to the error than just `An error occured`?
If there is a stacktrace, please provide it. Otherwise, this looks like it belongs more on CodeReview

Answer (score 1):

I use a function to validate model and prevent those errors. You can adapt it to your own code. The idea is checking :

- nan in the data
- check duplicate LpVariable names
- check LpVariable names with the unsupported characters -+[] ->/
- set LpSolverDefault.msg = 1 (before problem.solve(), show error)

> ```
> # Set solver message level
> pulp.LpSolverDefault.msg = 1
>
> # Check for duplicate and unsupported character in variable names
> all_vars = {**food_vars, **food_included_vars}
> var_names = [var.name for var in all_vars.values()]
>
> # Identify duplicate variable names
> duplicates = {name for name in var_names if var_names.count(name) > 1}
> if duplicates:
>     duplicate_list = ", ".join(duplicates)
>     print(ValueError(f"Duplicate LpVariable names detected: {duplicate_list}"))
>
> if len(var_names) != len(set(var_names)):
>     print(ValueError("Duplicate LpVariable names detected."))
>
> unsupported_chars_pattern = re.compile(r'[-+\[\] ->/]')
> for name in var_names:
>     if unsupported_chars_pattern.search(name):
>         print(ValueError(f"Unsupported character found in LpVariable name: {name}"))
>
> # Check for NaN inputs is omitted as it depends on external data integrity and variable definition
>
> print("*"*25, "Validation passed: duplicated and unsupported characters in LpVariable names.", "*"*25)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs suggest](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_debug.html#error-while-trying-to-execute-cbc-exe) in point (3) you have duplicated rows (constraints) and cbc does not like that. You probably saw the log messages that CBC wrote on the screen that go like this:

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.9.0 
Build Date: Feb 12 2015 
command line - /home/pchtsp/Documents/projects/cornflow/corn/cfvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/apis/../solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc /tmp/7f3f78bbc496475991ba842a3dd5a6a6-pulp.mps branch printingOptions all solution /tmp/7f3f78bbc496475991ba842a3dd5a6a6-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 370 COLUMNS
Duplicate row C0000189 at line 2412 <     X0000084  C0000189   1.000000000000e+00 >
Duplicate row C0000199 at line 2413 <     X0000084  C0000199   1.000000000000e+00 >
Duplicate row C0000245 at line 2414 <     X0000084  C0000245  -1.000000000000e+00 >
Duplicate row C0000246 at line 2415 <     X0000084  C0000246  -1.000000000000e+00 >
Duplicate row C0000247 at line 2416 <     X0000084  C0000247  -1.000000000000e+00 >
Duplicate row C0000248 at line 2417 <     X0000084  C0000248  -1.000000000000e+00 >
Duplicate row C0000249 at line 2418 <     X0000084
(..)
Duplicate row C0000276 at line 3077 <     X0000110  C0000276   1.000000000000e+00 >
At line 235234 RHS
At line 235600 BOUNDS
At line 253243 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 365 rows, 16311 columns and 122860 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 15290 errors
There were 15290 errors on input
** Current model not valid
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
** Current model not valid
```

So you see there are 15290 you have to solve :  )